# CSS Wrapper, Logo showing at the back

Tags: wrapper

Im just new to CSS:

And my problem is My Logo shows up but it's in the back and Should I put my div:top-most into the wrapper? because if I put my div:top-most, it will be shown along with the logo, but I want my lime color to be put on the max width of my browser..

Here's my HTML Code

```
<body>
<div id="top-most">
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<img alt="logo" src="images/logo.png" /><div id="wrapper">      
</div>


<div id="header">
    <p>Put something here</p>
</div>
</body>
```

And here's my CSS Code:

```
#top-most           { background-color: lime; height:51px ;width:100%; position:absolute; }

#wrapper            {  width :960px; height:100px ; overflow:hidden; margin:0px auto; }

#logo               { margin: 19px 0 0 10px; position:absolute; top: 0px; z-index:2; }

#header             { margin: 30px  0 0 20px; float:right; width: 750px;   }
#header p           { color: #979899; }
```

And here's the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe1Td.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Hello :) you need to put #wrapper in #top-most.

```
<body>
<div id="top-most">
<div id="wrapper">
<img alt="logo" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />   
</div>
</div>
<div id="header">
<p>Put something here</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I edited your Css code too.

```
#top-most           { background-color: lime; padding: 5px; position:absolute; }
#wrapper            {  width :960px; height:100px ; overflow:hidden; margin:0px auto; }
#logo               { margin: 19px 0 0 10px; position:absolute; top: 0px; z-index:2; }
#header             { margin: 30px  0 0 20px; float:right; width: 750px;   }
#header p           { color: #979899; }
```

You don't need padding: 5px; in #top-most but it will look better
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7hbdf/)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply, but it didn't work, 

This is the code that you did:

http://imgur.com/BMnwOA4

But The outcome that I wanted to is like this 

http://imgur.com/WCCpRJg

Where the top-most and the wrapper is in together, Idk how, but I also tried top-most position:absolute then it disappeared.